# TextView alignment in the TableRow

Tags: android, android-xml, android-tablelayout

There are two TableRows in the TableLayout, and each TableRow contains two TextViews:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

    </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="63dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textHall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textPrice"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

If `textHall` contains a short `Word`, `textTitle` (`Some Text`) located at the correct position:

[image: scr1]

But if `textHall` contains a long `Second Word`, before `textTitle` (`Some Text`) appears a large indentation:

[image: scr2]

What is the reason?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should give weight for your layouts and rows. I adapted your code. Here is the one that should be.

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="10:30" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Some Text" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="63dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textHall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Some Word" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textPrice"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="200" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>
```

You can put any margin value for your second row as you wish.

Hope this may help.

Answer (score 1):

Your `textHall` and `textTime` both fall into same column and the width of that column is set to the width of textHall(as this is having more width) as a result your  `textTime` textview's width is increasing when you increase text in `textHall`.